# Apply on an eventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events

I'am trying to use some values from the "upper" function in the "inner" function:

```
function Load(el, script)
{
    el.addEventListener('click',
        function (e)
        {
            this.test = "testing";
            script.apply(this, arguments);
        }, false);
};

Load(document.getElementById("panel"),
    function (e)
    {
        alert(test); // test is undefined
    });
```

The above example doesn't work, it says `test` is undefined.

But the following works:

```
function A(B)
{
  this.test = "bla";
  B.apply(this);
}
function B()
{
  alert(test);
}
A(B);
```

What's the difference? How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is a property on the element at that point, so you need to reference it like that:

```
Load(document.getElementById("panel"),
function (e)
{
    alert(this.test); // "testing"
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/4fgfM/).  The difference is that in the first example `this` refers to the `id="panel"` element and the property is set there.  In the second example `this` refers to the global object, or `window`, so `test` is a global variable that works when you go to access it.

Comment: Hmm thanks!! Is there a way to allow me to reference `test` without using `this.` ?

Comment: @BrunoLM - Nope...you have to have some context, unless it's a global or local variable (and it won't be in the handler) you need to reference it from the object it's on.

Comment: @BrunoLM `test` and `this.test` are two different variables.  You cannot reference one and get the value of the other.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, when you call `A()`, `this` refers to the `window` object since that's the scope in which `A()` runs.  All global variables also belong to the `window` object, so in that context, `test`, `this.test` and `window.test` are all the same entity.

In the first example, however, `this` refers to the element on which the handler was called, so `this.test` (which is defined) is the same as `"#panel".test` but is different from `test` and `window.test` (which are not defined).

Answer (score 0):

You should accept Nick Craver's answer, I'm just clarifying here with some more code:

```
function Load(el, script)
{
    el.addEventListener('click',
        function (e)
        {
            this.test = "testing";  // sets el.test="testing" ('cos this==el)
            script.apply(this, arguments);
        }, false);
};

Load(document.getElementById("panel"),
    function (e)
    {
        alert(test); // alerts window.test, not el.test
    });
```

```
function A(B)
{
  this.test = "bla"; // sets window.test="bla" ('cos this==window)
  B.apply(this);
}
function B()
{
  alert(test); // alerts window.test
}
A(B);
```